# Python - regexp to check if string is TLD domain

Tags: python, regex

I have form's field which accept string representing polish domain name (ends with .pl)

I need to check:

1. if string is a proper polish domain name (ends with .pl)
2. domain is top-level ( ie: domainname.pl) or 2-nd level: domainname.net.pl, domainname.something.pl

Do you have any suggestion how such regexp should look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot match all possible top-level domains with a regex, and the list of what *is* a TLD changes from time to time.

Use a library to extract the TLD instead, like [`tldextract`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract) or [`publicsuffix`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix/).

Demo:

```
>>> import tldextract
>>> tldextract.extract('domainname.net.pl')
ExtractResult(subdomain='', domain='domainname', suffix='net.pl')
>>> tldextract.extract('www.domainname.net.pl')
ExtractResult(subdomain='www', domain='domainname', suffix='net.pl')
>>> from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList
>>> psl = PublicSuffixList()
>>> psl.get_public_suffix('domainname.net.pl')
'domainname.net.pl'
>>> psl.get_public_suffix('www.domainname.net.pl')
'domainname.net.pl'
```

`tldextract` gives you a parsed result, while `publicsuffix` merely gives you the domain name that still is considered one entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a regex for that, i would go with something like this:

```
^([a-z0-9-]+.)?([a-z0-9-]+).pl$
```